# Community Login Page Title - Tab shows as "Login Template Title" before loading

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, napili, lightning-community

For our Napili Customer Community - if I text or post the the link of our Login page, it shows with a title of "Login Template Title".  We are using our own Theme/Layout/Lightning Component on the default login page, if that makes a difference.

Whenever you go the Login page, that title also shows very briefly before displaying the actual Title set in the Community Builder.  I cant find any others with a similar problem, so I feel I am missing something obvious.

Can someone point me to a workaround? I need to be able to text/post the link and have the appropriate Title show in the preview.

This seems to be a similar post, with no solution: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DvgQAAS

============

To note - for non-login pages, the Community Title shows up before loading the page title, as expected

Comment: Still looking for this.  I will update the answer if I find anything out myself.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title of the login page (or any other page) via settings:

[image: Change title of page]

Comment: Yes, we have this set.  Once the page loads, this title shows correctly.  But for a brief second before it loads, it flashes the "Login Template Title" title.

This isnt the worst thing in the world, but if we text the link, the preview also has the preview named as "Login Template Title", instead of 
 "Company> Login Page"

Answer (score 1):

Check your Site Title.

From Builder, go to Settings > General > Site Title.

[image]